# How to shut off fabric8 cluster and services

Tags: fabric8

I have the default fabric8 cluster running from this setup tutorial: https://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/minishift.html

What is the command to shut off all the services or the cluster altogether?

Comment: You can run minishift without arguments and it should show a list of commands you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
minishift stop
```

is the command to stop the VM, openshift and all services.

You can start it later if you wish